# Google Analytics API with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, oauth-2.0, google-analytics-api

I am trying to add Google analytics API to my Rails Appication using Oauth.

I am using `google-api-client` gem and using `http://readysteadycode.com/howto-access-the-google-analytics-api-with-ruby` as a reference.

Am able to create to create **Client Object** but when I am trying to access data

```
class GoogleController < ApplicationController

  def redirect
    client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new({
      client_id: GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID,
      client_secret: GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_SECRET,
      authorization_uri: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
      scope: Google::Apis::AnalyticsV3::AUTH_ANALYTICS_READONLY,
      redirect_uri: 'http://skreem.dev:3000/auth/google/callback'
    })

    redirect_to client.authorization_uri.to_s
  end

  def callback
    client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new({
      client_id: GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID,
      client_secret: GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_SECRET,
      token_credential_uri: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
      redirect_uri: 'http://skreem.dev:3000/auth/google/callback',
      code: params[:code]
    })

    response = client.fetch_access_token!
    session[:access_token] = response['access_token']

    redirect_to url_for(:action => :analytics)
  end

  def analytics
    client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(access_token: session[:access_token])

    service = Google::Apis::AnalyticsV3::AnalyticsService.new
    service.authorization = client

    @account_summaries = service.list_account_summaries
  end

end
```

and am using correct access token but getting following error

```
Sending HTTP get https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accountSummaries?
Caught error Missing token endpoint URI.
Error - #<ArgumentError: Missing token endpoint URI.>
```